# Is it possible to resolve merge conflict for only specific files after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I was doing a git rebase. There were many merge conflicts during the rebase, and i had to resolve them manually. After the rebase, i have found out that i have made a mistake in resolving conflicts for some files. I would like to resolve the merge conflict again, but only for these files.

Is this possible at all? If it helps, i have only done a git add on these files. I have not committed anything yet.

Thanks,
Kartik

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `git merge --interactive`. This should give you finer control over the merge process.